# How to integrate Spring boot application with Neo4J HA Cluster?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Here is my current configuration class. I am using local neo4j instance. I want to change configuration to connect to neo4j HA cluster. I am aware that clustering facility is available in neo4j enterprise edition.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("io.sample")
@PropertySource("classpath:neo4j.properties")
public class PersistentContext {

   @Value("${neo4j.driverClassName}")
   private String driverClassName;

   @Value("${neo4j.connectionUrl}")
   private String connectionUrl;

   @Value("${neo4j.username}")
   private String username;

   @Value("${neo4j.password}")
   private String password;

   /**
     * Creates session factory
     * 
     * @return {@link SessionFactory} neo4j session factory
   */
   @Bean
   public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      return new SessionFactory(configuration(), 
     "io.sample.model");
   }

   /**
    * Creates neo4j transcationManager by passing session factory
    * 
    * @return {@link Neo4jTransactionManager} transaction manager for 
      neo4j
    * @throws Exception
    *             when failed to create neo4j transaction manager
   */
   @Bean
   public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws 
   Exception {
    return new Neo4jTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
   }

   /**
    * Creates configuration by setting driverClass, connectionUrl and
    * credentials
    * 
    * @return {@link org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration} instance for 
      neo4j
    *         configuration
    */
    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new 
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
       configuration.driverConfiguration()
      .setDriverClassName(driverClassName)
      .setURI(connectionUrl).setCredentials(username, password);
       return configuration;
    }
 }
```

And neo4j.properties file is as follow :-

```
neo4j.driverClassName=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver
neo4j.connectionUrl=http://localhost:7474
neo4j.username=neo4j
neo4j.password=root
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work out-of-the-box, but...(later)

You create for example three Neo4j instances: `neo4j-machine1`,`neo4j-machine2`,`neo4j-machine3` and set the necessary configs as explained [in the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/high-availability/configuration/#ha-configuration). With this config you can still connect to one of the machines via HTTP and it will take care about distributing the request.

Now the "but": If this machine goes offline you cannot get access to the cluster anymore. The better solution is to introduce a proxy server in your network. There is an example to configure a HAProxy [in the OGM docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:ha:ha-cluster:load-balancer).

Comment: Finally I created  causal cluster with 3 core servers and 1 read-replica .. and i am accessing it using bolt driver. But  problem with it is i am not able to specify multiple URI's  as version bolt driver version 2.1.5 not supporting multiple URI's